# What phenomena related to the solar system could produce the Bianchi VIIh pattern found in the CMB?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

Both the WMAP and the Planck maps for the CMB seem to suggest that there are asymmetries in the temperature distribution above and below a plane roughly aligned to the ecliptic plane, including a particularly cold spot in the southern ecliptic hemisphere:

http://sci.esa.int/planck/51559-hemispheric-asymmetry-and-cold-spot-in-the-cosmic-microwave-background/

The (artificially enhanced) pattern shown in the image in the above article appears strikingly similar to a left-handed flat-decoupled-Bianchi VIIh pattern that, if substracted, would eliminate a good portion of the anomalies observed in the CMB:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5086.pdf

However, the implications of the universe having a structure and momentum such that the Bianchi pattern emerges are contrary to all previous cosmological evidence suggesting otherwise.

Because this pattern seems somewhat congruent to the ecliptic plane, what motions or lensing distortions happening locally at the solar system scale could plausibly produce such a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of some grand cosmic alignment seems rather remote. The alignment of the plane of the ecliptic is random with respect to the plane of the Galaxy - it could literally have been anything. We know from looking for eclipsing binaries and transiting planets that the "ecliptic" planes of other stellar and planetary systems can be quite different to our own.

The only serious scientific work I have seen (there may of course be others)
to explain this weak feature (certainly not 5 sigma significant) could be foreground contamination of the CMB signal by material in the solar system itself. Possible culprits are zodiacal dust or dust in the Kuiper belt. The analysis teams for WMAP and Planck have tried to avoid such problems, but these seem to be the only possibilities that are considered and not wholly dismissed by [Schwarz et al. (2015)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07929) in their recent review of these issues.